# Connect two sites with long range antennae

Tags: networking, wireless-networking

I'm looking to connect two sites with [long range antennae](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00UZ048R6).  Each site has its own router and ISP.  What configuration changes will I need to make to each network such that clients on either network can communicate with clients on the other network?

This is a residential application--both sites have Archer C9 routers.

Comment: The problem you're facing is residential routers aren't designed for this, Archer C9's expect to be connected to a single upstream isp.   Even with alternative firmware for a residential router this is an unusual configuration.  What are you trying to achieve?  Would a VPN between both locations using the Internet solve the need?  Or are you trying to use the second locations isp to back up the first and vice versa?

Comment: The goal is to have high speed connectivity between the sites.  Both sites have residential ISPs which means I'm looking at 2mbps uplinks versus 150mbps via the wifi approach.  Backup ISPs is not the goal.

Comment: You aren't going to get 150 Mbps with Wi-Fi. First, you will never get anywhere near the advertised Wi-Fi bandwidth, especially at any sort of distance. Second, both sites will be using the same frequency on a half-duplex medium, and the means you will, at best, get half the bandwidth you may expect. If you get something implemented, you may find it at or below what you can do with a VPN, and have less reliability than the VPN. Are there any trees or water between the sites? That would really do a number on your Wi-Fi.

Comment: To get those kind of speeds over distance, you will need a commercial product, like a point to point backhaul microwave system, like Ubiquity or Airmux

Comment: Clearly @acejavelin didn't read my original question as I linked to a Ubiquity product that advertises 25km+ range.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Naysayers in the comments are all demonstrably wrong.

Further, The Ubiquity devices you linked to are an excellent tool for the job, and - provided your area is not to noisy in the appropriate band, you should be able to get high performance - with no additional hardware - these are not antennas, they are antennas with Access Point functionality built in.

I've not used these exact devices, but from their manual it looks to me like you would configure them and get them talking to each other when they are close to each other by setting one up as an  Access Point and the other as a station or client, then mount and aim them, using Ubiquities software to help get the strongest signal.

Once you have this done, each side would present as an ethernet port to your router, and you just plug it in - ie from your routers point of view its simply a long piece of ethernet cable.

Comment: Hey thanks for the answer.  I'll just be sure that both networks are running on different subnets and then will add static routes on both sides.  The only issue I'm running into is that there may be a hill in the way.  My assumption is that any landmass will make this an impossible project and that line of sight is a requirement.

Comment: Line  of site is pretty close to a requirement, yes.  In fact, you ideally want more then just line of site, you want line of site + a bit of space arround it (look up  fresnel zone).    The 2.4 gig band can penetrate some things,  but not a hill.  You will probably need to stick some kind of repeater on the hill (or configure that as the AP, and have 2 AP clients point at it).    If power is an issue, its not unheard of to power these things with a solar panel and batteries, but I think there is significant cost.

Comment: The Ubiquiti devices can be operated in "router" mode, which is what you would need. You assign each device an IP address on its local network and you can add static routes in your existing routers to point to the local Ubiquiti device for IP addresses on the other network.